# Twig: render vs include

Tags: symfony, twig

I am creating an online store.
I have a performance problem if I use the twig function "render" instead of "include".

Here is the code that displays a product catalog:

catalog controller:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/StoreBundle/Controller/Product/Catalog.php

namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Controller\Product;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class CatalogController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Template()
     */
    public function productAction(\Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product\Category $category)
    {
        $qb = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('StoreBundle:Product')
            ->createQueryBuilder('product')
            ->select('partial product.{id, token, name}')
            ->innerJoin('product.categoryRelation', 'categoryRelation')
            ->where('categoryRelation.category = :category_id');

        $qb->setParameters(array(
            'category_id'  => $category->getId(),
        ));

        $products = $qb->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        return $this->render('StoreBundle:Product\Catalog:product.html.twig', array(
            'category' => $category,
            'products' => $products,
        ));
    }
}
```

... template for catalog controller:

```
{# src/Acme/StoreBundle/Resources/views/Product/Catalog/product.html.twig #}
{% extends 'AcmeDemoBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ category.name }}</h1>

    <ul>
    {% for product in products %}
        <li>
            {#% render "StoreBundle:Product:show" with { product: product } %#}
            {% include "StoreBundle:Product:show.html.twig" with { product: product } %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

... product controller:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/StoreBundle/Controller/Product.php

namespace Acme\Enter\StoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

use Enter\StoreBundle\Entity\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Template()
     */
    public function showAction(Product $product)
    {
        return array('product' => $product);
    }
}
```

... simple (but more complex in future) template for product controller:

```
{# src/Acme/StoreBundle/Resources/views/Product/show.html.twig #}
{{ product.name }}
```

So if I use:

```
{% include "StoreBundle:Product:show.html.twig" with { product: product } %}
```

...all ok: 147ms and 4608Kb memory.

But when I need a controller to display the product:

```
{% render "StoreBundle:Product:show" with { product: product } %#}
```

...my script consumes too much time and memory: 3639ms and 17664Kb memory!

How to increase speed and reduce memory consumption by using the controller?

Comment: Are you in dev or prod mode? The difference can be surprising.

Comment: I used the "dev" mode.
When I tried to "prod" mode, I was surprised - the application was very quick.

Comment: Dev does a lot of logging and has most important caches disabled. You should try to compare dev and prod with xdebug to see the sort of changes going on internally. It might reduce the urge to optimize such things in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Each render call spawns a new request, with the performance degradation issue that you are describing. I don't think there is much you can do about that but using esi caching, so that single fragments coming from render calls can be cached. Otherwise you could try to revise your logic to reduce the usage of render calls.

Comment: But it's still surprising that one request with `include` takes 147ms/4.5MB and a request that uses `render` once (and thus also spawns just one sub-request that shouldn't take more than 147ms) takes up 4000ms/17.5MB. We have the same problem in a project right now but with memory usage explosions like 150MB (~6 subrequests).

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but the basic idea is that include basically "copy-pastes" its content instead of the command.

Whereas render command must create the controller first, initialize it, run the corresponding function etc. So who knows what heavy artillery is hidden inside this controller's or parent's classes, constructors and so on?

Also remember, that even included templates are rendered. So you even might get recursions or something similar when rendering from twig. Personally I try avoiding rendering anything outside of controller's return.

Plus as mentioned by Louis-Philippe Huberdeau in comments, dev environment can drastically differ from prod mode because of different options and logging.

As for advices - try avoiding putting logic in your templates, or try using static objects that are often used in templates to reuse them instead of creating new ones over and over. And render stuff from controllers only