# Symfony2: login from each page

Tags: authentication, symfony

I have a **Symfony2** Web application which requires user *login* to perform such useful operations. In Symfony, you can put a link to the login page and then the security handled by the framework do the rest. You have to define the route for the login page in the *security.yml* configuration file.

I want to know if **is it possible** and **how** to let the user log in each page of the site (e.g. by inserting the login form on top of the page). This will save a page load and will not bother users.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to do this is to have all your templates extend a base template. I.E, in all your Twig templates have something like

```
{% extends 'YourBundle::base.html.twig' %}
```

In base.html.twig render a controller which renders the login form. To do this, in base.html.twig do something like:

```
{% render "YourBundle:Security:loginForm" %}
```

Then create a controller action, something like:

```
public function loginFormAction()
{
    $loginForm = //create the form
    return $this->render('YourBundle:Security:loginForm.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $loginForm,
    }
}
```

And finally in your loginForm.html.twig render the form.

Comment: Don't this provide such security issue?

Comment: ? sorry, I don´t understand what you mean?

Comment: I just want to know if there is such security pitfall in doing your solution. I guess no, because I'm rendering a controller which should be secure. However, if I want to use a secure connection (https) to the login page, I also have to use a secure connection for all the pages that render the login form. Isn't it?

Comment: Only the connection that sends the login post data needs to be secure

Comment: Yes, your reasoning makes sense... :) I'm going to implement your solution! If it works, I will accept it! However, I will add a +1 tomorrow (no upvotes for today). Thanks...

Comment: Ok! It works fine! Thanks a lot! Muchas gracias :) I have a final question. Get a look at [this site](http://www.yoox.com/): they load the login form at runtime with an Ajax call! Why? Has it sense?

Comment: I suppose they are doing it for a reason but I don´t think it is really neccessary

Comment: maybe the reason is to avoid load the form in every request. it could make sense if the login controller is big or need to do many operations.

Comment: @Ztere0 Yes, it could be reasonable. One [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077097/twig-render-vs-include) affirms that with **Symfony2** it is better to include a template than to render a controller. But I think that the answer provided by Aldo Stracquadanio is wrong, since there are no server request from a client. In fact I believe that the controller is rendered server side when one render the whole template. Isn't it? Of course, rendering a controller costs the computational time required to execute the controller lines...

Comment: I think that it is false that every render call spawns a new request. That would be mad. I don´t think you should bother about any of this. In prod mode everything is cached and fast as hell

Comment: Of course, everything is rendering in server side, but is not the same do everything in the same action, or render two different actions. You can test it easy, include a twig template and later, in other test, render it; look at the memory usage in the Symfony2 bar, this test will clarify the concept

Comment: @Ztere0 Ok, but it is very different from asserting that "Each render call spawns a new request".

Comment: ahh ok, I had not completely understood your previous question. I think that is just one request, as say @Carlos Granados, could be mad, but I can not ensure it.

Comment: Just wanted to mention, since Symfony 2.2 it's `{% render(controller( "YourBundle:Security:loginForm")) %}`

Answer (score 1):

Symfony2 firewall uses `_username, _password, _remember_me and _target_path` in its login action you defined in security.yml.

You can on every page you want (in the header for example) place a form (using a formBuilder, a formType or directly to fields in your template, up to you) that use these form names and send them to your login action. Symfony will automatically handle that and make the rest for you!