# Rendering options for an item in a loop, in a CRUD view

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'll try to explain this as clear as possible. I'm working on a rather large project and have created a CrudController. This controller has some default actions (`indexAction`, `createAction`, `archiveAction`...). I've also created some corresponding views.

- The `edit.html.twig` view will draw the form with the form_widget() function
- The `list.html.twig` view gets a data array and a (configurable) columns array. This draws a simply table with the required columns **AND** some action buttons (by default an edit and archive button).

The idea is that I am now able to rapidly develop my application: I create a new Entity, Repository, FormType and lastly a Controller that extends CrudController instead of BaseController. In my EntityController, I make sure that the configuration for my CrudController is correct (entity names, pointers to the FormType...). This all works like a charm.

However, I've come to the point where I have an Entity (Project) that needs some additional actions (beside Edit and Archive), namely "Render" or "Download" (when rendering is done). 
As I didn't want to completely overwrite my list view for this one entity just to add the extra actions and as I'll come across this scenario again, I decided to try and move the rendering of the actions out of the list view: I created an `actions.html.twig` view that would render just the actions and an `actionsAction` that would add the additional actions, based on the given project's status (should it show a Render button or a Download button?).

In my `list.html.twig` I used:

```
{% for row in data %}
    {{ render(controller(entityControllerActionsAction, {'id': row.id})) }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

However, it turned out render is quite the memory hog, and as soon as I display some entities in the list, it causes a "memory exhausted" error. A page that only used 12MB before now suddenly used more than 128MB (the memory limit), which is simply unacceptable. Also loading times increased massively

I'm looking for a decent, object-oriented, [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) solution to this problem.

- Is there a reason why the render() function would be such a memory and performance hog here? If I could reduce that, the problem would be solved.
- Would there be a way to mimick the render() function or use something different.

I'm not looking for prebuilt code or anything, but rather advice on which direction to proceed in. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I remember from ZF1 a similar problem: using partials leaded to a large amount of used memory as a new instance of the view was created if I remember correctly. Could you work with a block structure instead : define a default actions block and overwrite it for the project entity?

Comment: That's one thing I was indeed considering, however, it means creating a new view that extends the crud list view. It's a bit less hassle free, but might be the best solution.

Comment: Ah, have a look at this issue, it is as I guessed, "render" spawns a new request: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077097/twig-render-vs-include - I'll add it as an answer for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077097/twig-render-vs-include) "render" spawns a new request and increases memory usage therefore. Try using with a block structure instead which defines a default actions block. Overwrite this for the project entity.