# How to show different menus for different urls - Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm working on the frontend of a project using Symfony2. I'm stock with something that must be simple, but it's costing me a lot of time.

layout.html.twig is located at /FrontBundle/Resources/views with the following lines

```
 {% include 'SitewebFrontBundle::sidemenu.html.twig' %}

 {% block sidemenu %}{% endblock %}
```

sidemenu.html.twig is also located at /FrontBundle/Resources/views.

Side menu has different content depending on the page been viewed. The urls are:

```
address.com/menu1/...
address.com/menu2/...
address.com/menu3/...
```

What I want to do is to create a statement on sidemenu.html.twig following a logic like:

```
if {{ app.request.requesturi }} has /menu1/
   show menu1 
else if {{ app.request.requesturi }} has /menu2/
   show menu2
else
   show menu3
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Is the menu found in the url as a variable (ie, `path: /{menu}/page` where menu can be menu1, menu2 or menu3) meaning that each page can have the 3 different menus or does each route only have access to the same menu (ie, `path: /menu1/page` so the specified menu is hardcoded into the route)?

Answer (score 0):

Generate your `sidemenut.html.twig` by a passed parameter:

```
# sidemenu.html.twig
{% if requestUri is not defined %}
    {% set requestUri = 'menu3' %}
{% endif %}

# render your routes here like so:
<a href="{{ path('route-name-1', {menu: requestUri}) }}">Route 1</a>
# ...
```

And now include the `sidemenu.html.twig` with parameters:

```
# this will result in the requestUri variable to be menu1:
{% include 'SitewebFrontBundle::sidemenu.html.twig' with {includeUri: 'menu1'} %}

# use the request uri as a parameter:
{% include 'SitewebFrontBundle::sidemenu.html.twig' with {includeUri: app.request.requesturi} %}

# this will fallback to 'menu3':
{% include 'SitewebFrontBundle::sidemenu.html.twig' %}
```

For more questions check out:

- [The docs about including templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-templates)
- [An evaluation about include vs. render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077097/twig-render-vs-include)

Comment: Should that be requestUri on the with in the second code block?

Comment: It could be. But it can be any other value as well. I've added it for clarification though.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [KnpMenuBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle). then create merge all your menus under a single root.e.g: make a menu like

```
Menu
    menu1
       foo
    menu2
    ...
```

then make a [twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html), inject the `request` into it, and find which branch (menu) you have to display:

```
//in your extension class:
findBranch(){
    $path = $this->request->getPathInfo();
    $path = trim($path, '/');
    $parts = explode('/', $path);
    $branch = $parts[0];
    return $branch;

}
```

then in your template find the active branch using the extension and render it with using the [built-in method](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/bdfc95da5ff7e4e67f948aaa9ea5da835a3a9088/Resources/doc/index.md#rendering-menus)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just put all menus into one twig and include them with a variable to determine what menu should be used? Or you can send required name to template from your controller. Because putting such logic into twig usually is a bad idea